# If construct displaying only else value - PHP

Tags: php

Here is my statement:

```
if($row_x['xfield']==$_POST['x1'] AND $row_x['yfield']==$_POST['y'])
{
   echo "ok";
}
else {
   echo "invalid";
}
```

When both are not equal to each other, it must display 'invalid' else, 'ok'.  But in this case it displays 'invalid' whether it is valid or not.

Any clues to why?

Comment: Um, since you have an higher rep.. I'm unsure.. since when did AND replace && in PHP?

Comment: what output of `echo $row_x['xfield']. '==' . $_POST['x1'];`?

Comment: @LewsTherin `AND` and `OR` are able to be used in as operators, but `&&` and `||` have a higher order of priority.

Comment: @LewsTherin I used both && and AND

Comment: @Fluffeh Used both && and AND does not work though.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov ages ago as in 3000 years ago? ;)
Jean sorry I have no idea, you probably want to echo what the variable contains..

Comment: @Jean The syntax looks fine, short of funky data that you would have to validate, I simply cannot see anything that visibly stands out as wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Output can be anything.  The db value is equated to the form post.

Comment: @Jean well if output can be anything then error can be anywhere

Comment: Replace `AND` with `OR` and it'll show ok when at least one is equal

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov can you post that output error as an answer. thanks.  It was exactly that.

Comment: Your code is ok, make sure your `$row` and `$_POST` are getting the values: [CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/EcGhQjrL)

Comment: are you sure it is `x1`?

Answer (score 2):

You said 'when BOTH are NOT equal'... implying you would want to use '!=' instead of '==' in your comparisons. See this T/F chart for &&:

```
--------------
| X | && | Y |
--------------
| F | F  | F |
--------------
| F | F  | T |
--------------
| T | F  | F |
--------------
| T | T  | T |
--------------
```

The X statement must be true AND the Y statement must be true. In your example

```
$row_x['xfield']==$_POST['x1']
```

must be TRUE as well as

```
$row_x['yfield']==$_POST['y']
```

But if I read your question you will want to have both statements as FALSE to show 'invalid'. So you'll need to substitute '==' for '!=' in each statement.

Comment: Using the logic in the question, if unless both conditions are met, it *should* drop down into the the `else` clause.

Comment: His statement is correct: "When both are not equal to each other, it must display **'invalid'** "

Comment: Read his code and what he needs again. Everything is correct. You just rephrasing the same thing OP already has

Comment: "When both are not equal to each other, it must display 'invalid', else 'ok'" he states, implying either an OR comparison or his && comparison inverted, right? * getting confused*

Answer (score 1):

its because the any of them is not true or both

you are using the &&/AND so both must be match since you are getting the else result it mean any of them is not equal or both

you can check this by below method

```
if($row_x['xfield']==$_POST['x1']){
   echo ' xfiekd  is = to x1';
   if($row_x['yfield']==$_POST['y']){
     echo ' yfiekd  is = to y and aslo 1 is true';
   }else{ echo 'y is false' }


}
else{
   echo ' xfiekd  is = to x1' is false;
   if($row_x['yfield']==$_POST['y']){
     echo ' yfiekd  is = to y and aslo 1 is true';
   }else{ echo 'y is false' }


}
```

to get in if function body on true at least one condition you need to use the `||` instead of the AND

difference betwen AND an OR

truth table for AND

```
  a    b

true  true   = true
true  false  = false
false  false = false
false  true  = false
```

truth table for OR

```
  a    b

true  true   = true
true  false  = true
false true   = true
false false  = true
true  false  = true
```

Comment: @hayden check this now .. is it ok or should i need to elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

Replace `AND` with `OR` and it'll show `ok` when at least one is equal

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row_x['xfield']==$_POST['x1'] OR $row_x['yfield']==$_POST['y'])
{
   echo "ok";
}
else {
   echo "invalid";
}
```

alternative

```
if($row_x['xfield']!=$_POST['x1'] AND $row_x['yfield']!=$_POST['y'])
{
   echo "ok";
}
else {
   echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: we can not use the OR as a substitute of AND since OP wants to check both